# Disable Button based on a cell value is 0

Tags: google-apps-script

I have made a script where if I click the button the data will be sent to another Sheet from "STD" to "INDEX 1". This works properly. I need help in two things,

1. If a cell Suppose D1 is equals to 1 then the button will be disabled.
2. The button will remain disable until the script finished.
   Sharing the Script. Please help.

```
function adm() {
    const mainFunctionName = "adm"; // Function name of this function.
    const alertFunctionName = "alert1";
    const drawings = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("STD").getDrawings();
    const drawing = drawings.filter((e) =\> e.getOnAction() == mainFunctionName);
    if (drawing.length == 1) {
    drawing\[0\].setOnAction(alertFunctionName);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    sd();
    drawing\[0\].setOnAction(mainFunctionName);
    }
    }
    function alert1() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("NOW SAVING");
    }

    function sd() {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    const pt = ss.getSheetByName("STD")
    const pcons = ss.getSheetByName("INDEX1")
    const clr1 =\["F15:I34"\]

    const pt1 = \["B1","B8","B9"\]

    const vs = pt.getRange("A15:T34").getValues().map((\[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l,      
    m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v\]) =\> \[k,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,v\]);
    pcons.getRange(pcons.getLastRow() + 1, 1, vs.length, vs\[0\].length).setValues(vs);

    pt1.forEach(f =\> pt.getRange(f).clearContent())
    clr1.forEach(f =\> pt.getRange(f).clearContent())

     }
```

Comment: This could be done easily if you would utilize an html button in the side bar.

Comment: In your drawing functions simply put a check `if{ sheet.getRange("D1").getValue() === 1 } return;`  but I don't know how you reenable the drawging function.

Comment: @Cooper thanks a ton, But can you please show me how.

Answer (score 0):

**Disable button upon script execution and enable upon completion**

gs:

```
function shareData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0")
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues()
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  osh.getRange(osh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
  return;
}

function launchMyButtonBar() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah2'));
}
```

html('ah2.html'):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
   <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Share Data" onClick="shareData();">
    <script>
      function shareData() {
        document.getElementById("btn1").disabled = true;
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(() => {document.getElementById("btn1").disabled=false;})
        .shareData();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)